# decimal extension method ambiguous

Tags: c#, visual-studio, extension-methods

i created an extension method for decimal AsCurrency(this decimal amount)

when i build i will get an error

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>   'CurrencyHelper.AsCurrency(decimal)' and
>   'CurrencyHelper.AsCurrency(decimal)'

whate hell? if i clear solution, it will build again. next time it will fail again.

Is the problem with decimal or has there gone something wrong with my solution?

Has anyone encountered  same problem?

**Edit**

Extensions are in one assembly. CurrencyHelper has only one definition.

here's the code:

```
public static class CurrencyHelper
{
    public static string AsCurrency(this decimal amount)
    {
        return ((decimal?) nr).AsCurrency();
    }

    public static string AsCurrency(this decimal? amount)
    {
        var cultureInfo = ...
        return (nr ?? 0).ToString("c2", cultureInfo);
    }
}
```

The idea is to format decimal value with needed cultureinfo and if amount is null, 0 is still provided

Comment: Do you perhaps have `CurrencyHelper` being defined in two different assemblies? perhaps you have shared the `.cs` file into both? that would lead to a conflict...

Comment: Could you have a project reference (correct) to the extensions assembly for one project, and a dll-reference (wrong) to that same assembly? Then you could get a version conflict where VS sees two versions of the same dll. Although I would then expect a "version conflict" error ...

Comment: it is defined and used in the same project. not anywhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. problem solved

seems like someone in our team added reference to project itself. Thanks for the tip, Hans